# How to stop a function if image tag tag is found in the string

Tags: php, html, string, function, codeigniter

I am trying to stop this function if "" is contained in the phrase

```
if (! function_exists('highlight_phrase'))
{
    /**
     * Phrase Highlighter
     *
     * Highlights a phrase within a text string
     *
     * @param string $str       the text string
     * @param string $phrase    the phrase you'd like to highlight
     * @param string $tag_open  the opening tag to precede the phrase with
     * @param string $tag_close the closing tag to end the phrase with
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function highlight_phrase(string $str, string $phrase, string $tag_open = '<mark>', string $tag_close = '</mark>'): string
    {

        if ($phrase != ucwords('<img>') && $str != ucwords('<img>')) {

            return ($str !== '' && $phrase !== '') ? preg_replace('/(' . preg_quote($phrase, '/') . ')/i', $tag_open . '\\1' . $tag_close, $str) : $str;
        }
    
    }
}
```

I have the above code but isn't working for me... Please I need help

This is how I use the function

```
 <?php $desc =  highlight_phrase($desc, "$keyword_4", '<span style="color:darkred; background-color: yellow; font-weight: bold;">', '</span>');  ?>
```

Comment: As far as I understand, you want your function 'highlight_phrase()' to work correctly if '$phrase' is an empty string? Is this what you asking for?Please make your question more explicit.

Comment: if $keyword_4 is not found inside a img tag

Comment: Please Add real data examples of what you want to see as output from the function... i.e. Show us your test cases for when it highlights and when it shouldn't.